# Float left combined with center element

Tags: html, css

How can I center the second element in a div without knowing the width of the first.

I want "foo" to float to the left and "bar" to be centered in the original div.  I can do this if I know the width of "foo":

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left;">foo</span>
    <span style="margin-left:-10px;">bar</span>
</div>
```

Is there another way to do this, without margin-left set to a static width?

Comment: `bar` to be centered of what? in the center of the `div` or in the center of the leftover of the `div` after the width of `foo`?

Comment: to be centered in the original div. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Center of the parent div?](http://jsfiddle.net/nzBzB/)

```
<div>
    <span id="f"> foo  foo  foo  foo  foo  foo  foo  foo </span>
    <span id="c">bar</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#f{
    float:left;
}
#c{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why.  What is the significance of using width:100px ?

Comment: Because otherwise it will fill the entire width of the parent. Technically it would still be centered, though probably not the way you want ;)

Comment: Note that `display:block` turns it into a block level element, which by default fills the entire width. In other words, with this solution you lose the automatic shrink-wrap behaviour of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to why you'd want this, but here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jL87v/

```
<div>
    <span class="foo">foo</span>
    <span class="bar">bar</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo { float: left; }
.bar {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    text-align:center;
}
.child1,.child2{
    text-align:left;
}
.child1{
    float:left;
}
.child2{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7 */
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7 */
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child1">foo</span>
    <span class="child2">bar</span>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6fMve/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the margin-left on the second element to 50%.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6fMve/